# Removing border color from input field using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Need your help.I have defined a function for validation.The textbox border changes to red once my validation fails.But doesnot change to black once the validation is passed.I do not know on how to change the color back to balck.PFB the code

```
function isNumeric(event) 
{
var keyCode = event.which;
var r = (keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || (keyCode >= 96 && keyCode <= 105) || (keyCode == 8) || (keyCode == 9) || (keyCode == 46) || (keyCode == 110)
 if (!r) 
{

 alert("Please enter only numbers");

}
 return r;
}
```

The code basically validates if a number/tab/delete/backspace/decimal point is entered in the textbox and if not, it will throw an error.

Comment: how the red border color is getting applied in first place. Some plugin or by your code ?

Comment: just add an else!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in else block

```
if (!r) 
{

   alert("Please enter only numbers");

}
else
{
    // make color black again here
}
```

Comment: The problem is I have 6 textboxes and I need to highlight only the one which throws the error and to change it back again to black once the validation is passed,I am new to javascript and I am not getting an idea as to where to start with

Comment: so do same validation code 6 different for 6 textboxes rather than code in one place. By this every texbox color will be changed individually

Comment: tried the validation 6 times for 6 textboxes and it works..But looking into performance I feel that would create redundancy..Is there any way so that the textbox which triggered the error can be passed as a parameter and the border color can be displayed accordingly?

Comment: yes you can create a single function for that and pass every information as parameter. Then you can avoid redundancy code and can use same code for multiple textboxes

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your inputs.The issue has been resolved.I had passed the parameter and the event(to fetch my keycode)to the function and evrything works fine